# Ruby LDAP to_hash method

Tags: ruby, ldap

Question regarding `ruby-ldap` gem.
It returns an `LDAP::Entry` object from search. It has a method called `to_hash`. The problem is that the values in the hash it returns are always arrays - even if there is only one value. 
Do you know if it's possible to change this behavior? I would like to have a `key -> String` pair when there is only one element instead of `key -> Array`.

Processing this hash later can be expensive, especially that it's pretty big in my case.

Comment: I'm skeptical that replacing those single-element arrays with their elements would help much with any performance problem. At the very least you should profile it to see what operations are actually taking up the most CPU time. There's a big disadvantage to what your proposing, which is that you would then have to check every time whether the element you're accessing is an array or not, which isn't free.

Comment: That's true, but I don't want to use Arrays, they pollute the JSON file witch unnecessary brackets, and generally I don't see a point in having them when a value is meant to be unique. It causes a lot of confusion. Problem is not solved till today.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, this is basically an LDAP-Issue: LDAP-Values are stored in arrays.
A simple solution could be have a custome helper, i.e.

```
def to_my_hash()
  @ldap_entry.attribute_names.each_with_object({}) do |key, hsh|
    val_arr = @ldap_entry[name]
    if val_arr.empty? 
      hsh[key] = nil
    elsif  val_arr.size == 1
      hsh[key] = val_arr.first
    else
      hsh[key] = val_arr
    end
  end
end
```